# Extract some string from a line using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a string,

```
. . . . . . . . . . . .starting  i-8f1031ed .. started  aashish.292 ec2-23-20-213-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com in 36 s
```

I want to extract,

```
ec2-2-2-2-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

using sed. Can you provide a way?

Comment: Why sed? And what's the general criteria for finding the part you want to extract?

Comment: Not specific sed the thing is i just want it to be extracted. In that case awk would also do.

Comment: OK, but what's the pattern? It's not just that exact string, or you could just use a literal.

Comment: Pattern should be, string starting with 'ec2' till the first white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "..." | sed 's/.*\(ec2[^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `awk`:

```
echo '...' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Or if you insist on `sed`:

```
sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/'
```

---

As it turns out the string in the question isn't what you actually want, i.e. you're not after the last "word". In that case you can get away with:

```
sed 's/.* \(.*amazonaws.com\).*/\1/
```

Comment: I doubt it is working. When i tried 

echo ". . . . . . . . . . . .starting  i-8f1031ed .. started  aashish.292 ec2-2-2-2-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com in 36 s" | sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/'

It gives out to be 's'

Comment: @AashishP It is working, I copy-pasted from my terminal. The string you pasted in this comment isn't the same you pasted in the question.

Comment: The string pasted in question is correct one and same as given in comment. Please check.

Comment: @AashishP I checked. In the question the string ends with `amazonaws.com`. In the comment it ends with `36 s`.

Comment: That's why I always ask for the criteria in questions like this. You can't assume the example is perfectly represenative.

Comment: @cnicutar darn! I am sorry that's my bad. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use grep:

```
grep -o 'ec[^ ]*' <<<". . . . . . . . . . . .starting  i-8f1031ed .. started  aashish.292 ec2-23-20-213-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com in 36 s"
```

Output:

```
ec2-23-20-213-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The string in question must have some recognizable pattern, for ex if we assume that the string is ending with .com always then this should work :-
`sed 's|^.* \([^ ]*\.com\).*$|\1|g'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string always starts with ec2:

`sed 's/\(ec2.*\)/\1/'`